# javascript onClick image(s) link

Tags: jquery, image, hyperlink, onclick

I need to know how I can have multiple images, when clicked, call/setup a javascript pop-up.

here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#my-link').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       $('.offerlink').click(function() {
        setTimeout('removegateway()', Delay*10);
       });
       setupgateway();
    });
```

here is my image/caller:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="my-link" onmouseover="over_image('img13');" onmouseout="off_image('img13')" style="position: absolute; top:362px; left: 364px;"/> 
  <img src="http://blah.png" border="0" name="img13"></a>
```

...it works fine when I put 'id="my-link"' next to one image, but when I try to put it next to more than one, only the first(first in the code) one call the pop-up. What do I need to change?

Comment: Wait, so are you asking how to call the same function on multiple images?

Comment: not sure what you are asking, also the code looks strange - it seems like you are missing "}" (you open near $('#my-link').click but you do not close it.

Comment: @mkk Actually, he closed `#my-link`.  He needs to close `document.ready`.

Comment: thanks for the comments. im not very competent in coding, especially in css, but in regards to whats closed and what isn't... this is just a little piece taken out from a much bigger code. maybe whats wrong isn't really wrong when you look at the whole code is what im saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a function for all images you will have to use a `class` instead of an `id`:

```
 $('.my-link').click(function(e) {
    // ...
 });


<img src="http://blah.png" class="my-link" />
<img src="http://blah.png" class="my-link" />
```